# Multiple condition in FindFirst satement

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Sub Main()
StartTime = Now()
TDate = CDate(Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YYYY"))
My = Environ("Username")
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Emp", dbOpenDynaset)
Criteria = "ID = '" & My & "' And From_Date >= '" & TDate & "' And To_Date <= '" & StartTime & "' "
rs.FindFirst Criteria
If rs.NoMatch Then
MsgBox "Record not found"
else
MsgBox "Record found"
end if
```

Please help to run this code as I would like to find first record between start date & end date.

Answer (score 0):

For a date you should use a "#" as enclosing character:

```
Criteria = "ID = '" & My & "' And From_Date >= #" & TDate & "# And To_Date <= #" & StartTime & "# "
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up date and time formatting:

```
Sub Main()

    ' Dim StartTime As Date
    ' Dim TDate As Date

    StartTime = Now
    TDate = DateValue(StartTime)
    My = Environ("Username")

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Emp", dbOpenDynaset)
    Criteria = "ID = '" & My & "' And From_Date >= #" & Format(TDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And To_Date <= #" & Format(StartTime, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#'"
    rs.FindFirst Criteria
    If rs.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "Record not found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Record found"
    End If

End Sub
```

However, it could be reduced to:

```
Sub Main()

    My = Environ("Username")

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Emp", dbOpenDynaset)
    Criteria = "ID = '" & My & "' And From_Date >= Date() And To_Date <= Now()"
    rs.FindFirst Criteria
    If rs.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "Record not found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Record found"
    End If

End Sub
```